# How to get value of the last day in the current month in awk

Tags: text-processing, awk, date, gawk

According to [link](http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/154293-how-can-i-get-first-day-pre-month.html) last day can be seen using this `date` command:

```
$ date -d "-$(date +%d) days -1 month"
Wed May 31 21:20:31 CEST 2017
```

My question is, how can I get **only**  the day and assign it to a variable, which I'll later use, like

```
awk '{day=system("date -d \"-$(date +%d) days -1 month\")"; print day)}'
```

so for example printing **day** will output only **31**. I know that date format needs to be formatted, but I fail to understand how to print only the last day from it.

Or if there is another simpler method in `awk` it will do job as well.

**EDIT**
Some very dirty workaround..

```
$ awk '{a=system("date -d \"-$(date +%d) days -1 month\"| cut -f 3 -d \" \""); }END{print a}'

31
```

Anyone has simpler/cleaner idea?

Comment: `$ date -d "-$(date +%d) days -1 month" +%d` to simply format the outer invocation of `date` perhaps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Last day of **current** month should be:

```
$ date -d "$(date +%Y-%m-01) +1 month -1 day"
Mon Jul 31 00:00:00 CEST 2017
```

My shortest:

```
awk '{a=system("date -d \"$(date +%Y-%m-01) +1 month -1 day\" +%d")}END{print a}'
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use a format string for the outer invocation of `date`:

```
$ date -d "-$(date +%d) days +1 month" +%d
31
```

Comment: +1 ... although I think it needs to be `+ 1 month` if the OP really wants the last day of the *current* month; possibly `"next month - $(date +%d) days"` captures the intent more clearly

Answer (score 1):

```
lastday=$(cal 07 2017|awk 'END{print day};{if (NF>0){day=$NF}}')
```

This plucks the last day value of the calendar's last line, ignoring blank lines.

A bit shorter is:

```
lastday=$(cal 07 2017|awk 'END{print day};{NF>0 && day=$NF}')
```

Comment: I need to get a day in awk script explicitly, so i can use it with awk, not with bash/shell. I am checking `awk` 'strftime()' function, but have no clue how to use it for my purpose.

Answer (score 1):

The last day of the **current** month is:

```
date -I -d "-$(date +%d) days +1 month"
```

How does it work? The `-d` option of the `date` command allows some flexibility to use plain words to describe dates in the future or the past that will be interpreted into a Linux date. For example, if the current date is 2023-06-11, the `date +%d` outputs only the day of the month which is 11. The description is then interpreted as "current date - 11 days + 1 month" which returns 2023-06-30 because of the `-I` option (ISO date format).

If you want just the day, use the output format `+%d` and assign it to a variable:

```
last_day=$(date -d "-$(date +%d) days +1 month" +%d)
```

Another variation is to force the current date to the 1st day of the month using a format that fixes the day of the month to 01 (`+%Y-%m-01`). Then the relative term `yesterday` adjusts the date to the last day of the prior month before advancing it the last day of the current month:

```
last_day=$(date -d "$(date +%Y-%m-01) yesterday +1 month" +%d)
```

The choice is yours.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
month=$(cal 07 2017)
lastday=${month: -24: 2}
echo $lastday
```

I'm using the calendar function to load the "month" variable with all of the days of the month and then picking off the last two characters. The example is for July of 2017 but it works with and month/year.